# Is there an efficient way to build positive-negative number pattern in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, nested-loops

hey im new in C programming here, currently i'm doing a self learning and have found this quest from some university module that hasn't been answered yet.
The [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3k8F.png) is to print the following pattern:

```
Input N = 3                   Input N = 4

Output                        Output
    1  -3   5                     1  -3   5  -7
   -2   4  -6                    -2   4  -6   8
    1  -3   5                     1  -3   5  -7
                                 -2   4  -6   8
```

i already tried to write but i couldn't find the best condition that suit this pattern. here's my code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int even(int input)
{
    int num;
    for(int i=2; i<=input*2; i+=2) {
        if (i == 2)
            printf("%d ", i * -1);
        else {
            if (i/2 <= 3 && i/2 >=2)
                printf("%d ", i * -1);
            else
                printf("d ",i);
        }
    }
}
int odd(int input)
{} /* i haven't code for the odd one yet because its almost similar with the even*/

int main ()
{
    int N;
    puts("provide N: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    even(N);
    odd(N);
    return 0;
}
```

and the result are shown here
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNYmM.png):

```
Provide N:
3
Result :
-2-4-6
```

which line should i working on?

Comment: Hint: `anything % 2` will always be `0` or `1`, so the result of `i % 2 <= 3 ` is always `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! gonna fix that and i'll update my progress @Yksisarvinen

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text but **post text as text**. Also format your code properly. Poorly formatted code is hard to work with.

Comment: you need +ve , -ve or even , odd ? I cannot see the Result as its a link

Comment: i need a combined number pattern like e.g "-1 3 -5 7 -9.." and i couldn't find the condition to fit the pattern @IrAM

Comment: You can do this with a single pair of nested loops. The absolute value at row j and col i is 2·(i + 1) for odd rows and 2·(i + 1) − 1 for even rows. The sign is a checkerboard pattern; it is −1 if (i + j) is odd and +1 otherwise. (Here, i and j start with 0 an go up to N − 1, as is conventional in C.)

Comment: @MOehm thank you! i'll keep it posted for the updates

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: "Hint: `anything % 2` will always be `0` or `1`" -- That is not quite correct. `anything %2` can also be `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

no if`s needed. Only simple math

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printPattern(int x)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < x; row++)
    {
        int neg = -1 + 2 * (row % 2);
        for(int num = 1; num <= x * 2; num += 2) 
            printf("%d ", (num + row % 2) * (neg *= -1));
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printPattern(4);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PvcWcP

Comment: i've never thought of that way. but this is the most efficient way, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

[edit] i already tried different things and this is my code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int EvenOdd(int);
int main (){
    int N;
    puts("provide N: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    EvenOdd(N);
    return 0;
}

int EvenOdd(int input)
{
    int k;
    for(int i=0; i<input; i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
           k=1;
        else
           k=2;
        for(int j=0; j<input; j++)
        {
           printf("%2d ", (i+j)%2 ? -k : k);
           k=k+2;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(i%2==0)?
            k=1 : k=2;` What's wrong with an `if`? Anyway, `k = (i%2==0)?1:2;`.

Comment: thank you for your correction, i thought it could simplified the code line, but conventional way looks better tho @KamilCuk

Comment: I have another idea, just take `(i+j)%2` instead of `((j%2!=0)&&(i%2==0))||((j%2==0)&&(i%2!=0))`. Like, `printf("%2d ", (i+j)%2 ? -k : k);`

Comment: thats a very good idea, already tried it and it works perfectly!